# Timestamp comparing is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some confusion in below code is it working properly ? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8nt1vt/1/)

```
var TodaysDate = new Date();                  
var cdd = TodaysDate.getDate();
var cmm = TodaysDate.getMonth()+1;
var cyy = TodaysDate.getFullYear();
var dates = '27-04-2015';
var dates1 = dates.split("-");
var newDate = dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2];
var currenttimestamp = new Date(cmm+'/'+cdd+'/'+cyy).getTime(); 



if(newDate < currenttimestamp){
    alert('test');
} else {
    alert('test1');
}
```

Comment: Please check it now my updated question

Comment: What is your question? "confusion" is too vague.

Comment: All the `cmm+'/'+cdd+'/'+cyy` stuff is completely useless. Basically, you get today's date, then you extract the day, the month and the year, then you use these numbers to find out today's date. Why make things simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to convert the newdate to timestamp

```
var newdate = new Date(dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2]).getTime();
```

code be simply write

```
var dates = '27-04-2015';
var dates1 = dates.split("-");
var newdate = new Date(dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2]).getTime();
var currenttimestamp = new Date().getTime(); // current time stamp

if(newDate < currenttimestamp){
    alert('test');
} else {
    alert('test1');
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8nt1vt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.getTime()` for both dates to compare them.

```
var dates = '27-04-2015';
var dates1 = dates.split("-");
var newDate = dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2];
newDate = new Date(newDate).getTime();
var currenttimestamp = new Date().getTime(); 
if(newDate < currenttimestamp){
    alert('test');
} else {
    alert('test1');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8nt1vt/4/)**

Comment: You can remove the first four lines, they're totally useless.

Comment: Uh, your first solution was much better. Now you put back some more useless stuff. All you had to do was deleting the first four lines.

Comment: Fair enough :) Did so